# Could this (unsafe) code crash the JVM?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jvm, unsafe

Slightly modified from [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/ff5a8683-4cc6-4214-9b40-1f5488e21618/entry/java_pointer_arithmetic_watch_wiuth_awe16?lang=en):

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class K {
    private static Unsafe unsafe;
    private static int fieldOffset;
    private static K instance = new K();

    static {
        try {
            Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            f.setAccessible(true);

            unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);

            fieldOffset = unsafe.fieldOffset(K.class.getDeclaredField("obj"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private Object obj;

    public synchronized static long toAddress(int o) {
        instance.obj = o;
        return unsafe.getLong(instance, fieldOffset);
    }

    public synchronized static Object toObject(long address) {
        unsafe.putLong(instance, fieldOffset, address);
        return instance.obj;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 20;

        System.err.println("x was = " + x);
        long addr = toAddress(x);
        System.err.println("&x = " + addr);
        x = 70;
        System.out.println("x is now " + x);
        long newAddr = toAddress(x);
        System.err.println("new (&x) = " + newAddr);

        System.out.println("Previous value of x is " + toObject(addr)); // !!!
    }
}
```

In particular, I'm worried about the line marked with `!!!`. If the original `x` gets garbage collected then its address will presumably be worthless.

My question is will the JVM segfault or will `toObject(BOGUS_VALUE)` always fail with a `NullPointerException` (which can be caught)?

As I'm sure most of you know, the `Unsafe` documentaton is spotty at best.

Comment: No. It will always throw NullPointerException earlier, at  `unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Why? ["If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, no it won't. This is a normal, I'd say canonical, way of getting a static field of a class. If theUnsafe was an instance variable, you'd be right, though.

Comment: Sorry, I just looked again. I thought OP was accessing `unsafe` in `K`, not the field here [`Unsafe`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html).

Comment: In this particular case, the Integer object (created by autoboxing) won't be garbage collected, because Integer keeps a reference to it in a static array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added some code that would potentially cause a GC before trying to retrieve the lost object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {
    new Object().toString();
}
System.out.println("Previous value of x is " + toObject(addr).getClass()); // !!!
```

and got a

```
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010e627c46, pid=49698, tid=6403
```

The address you have probably no longer points to something that could be considered an object. It is `Unsafe`.

Comment: I tried doing something similar but my GC wasn't kicking in. Looks like you were (un)luckier :) Thanks!